# Solving linear systems over $\mathbb{Z}/n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic

I am given the following system of linear equations:

$2x + 5y \equiv 6 $

$3x + 6y \equiv 5 $

and I am asked to solve it over the set $ \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \} $, that is, over $\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z}$.

Here is what I have done:

\begin{bmatrix}
    2 &5 &6\\
    3 &6 &5
\end{bmatrix}

I used row reduction to reduce this matrix to RREF (Reduced Row Echelon Form), using modular arithmetic for each elementary row operation.  The final RREF is this:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &0 &1\\
    0 &1 &5
\end{bmatrix}

Then we can read off the answer from the final matrix.

My three questions are:

1) Is this a valid approach?  If so, is this the standard/best approach to solve this type of problems?

2) How would I know, just looking at the RREF matrix, if the system has only one solution, no solution, or infinitely many solutions?  Is it just like dealing with any linear system over $\mathbb{R}$ (looking for any inconsistency, looking for any free variables)?

3) Can such a system (linear system over $\mathbb{Z}_m$) have exactly $n$ solutions, where $n$ could be anything in $\{1,2,3,...m\} $?

**Edit:**

I think the answer for my third question should be that the number of solutions can be either 0, 1 (unique solution), or exactly $m$ solutions.  Is this right/wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Andrew, I can't help but replace $\mathbb Z_n$ by $\mathbb Z/n$, at least, since in the larger world $\mathbb Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers, not a cyclic group of order $p$, and so on. I know that this is common usage, so I'm not meaning to be accusatory, but it's just not a "sustainable" notation... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is for a prime $p$...

(1) The approach is fine.

(2) Yes it is the same as it would be over $\mathbb{R}$; however, in the case of many solutions it won't be infinitely many solutions but rather $p^k$ where $k$ is the number of free variables.

(3) The number of solutions will be $0$ or a nonnegative integer power of $p$ (see (2)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Could you please refer me to the name of the theorem you used for 2) or a place where I can learn the details of this theorem?

Comment: I don't know of a name of a theorem; but basically linear equations being solved with coefficients in a field all follow the same theory.